# Do you "have a particular interest" or do you "have particular interest"?

Tags: adjectives, indefinite-articles

Maybe it's particular (!) to the "particular" adjective. Without it, it's fairly obvious that I "have an interest" is more correct than "I have interest". But when my interest is particular, I'm not sure if the indefinite article is either redundant or even incorrect.

Also, "interest" has a slightly different meaning when used with the "particular" adjective,
connoting a state of concern, as opposed to a discrete hobby or recreation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **I have a particular interest in grammar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the following would be considered grammatical:

1. I have a particular interest in soup.
2. I have particular interests.
3. I am particularly interested in soup
4. My interest in soup is particular.

I am not convinced that "I have particular interest in soup" is extremely grammatical. If you look at the [NGram usages](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+particular+interest+%2a%2C+have+%2a+particular+interest&year_start=1800), you notice that it is significantly less common than (1). But it *is* being used so people seem to think it sounds fine.

Unfortunately for your other premise, the [usage frequencies](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+%2a+interest%2Chave+interest+%2a&year_start=1800) for "have an interest" and "have interest" look fairly similar.

As far as I can tell, if one considers "have particular interest in" to be grammatical, you should also consider "have interest in" to be grammatical. I see nothing particularly interesting about "particular" in this context.